# Index for Abney Park Cemetery London UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, london, cemeteries

Does anyone know if the above cemetery has ever been indexed and if so is there an online database available either free or subscribed?

Answer (score 4):

The burials at [Abney Park Cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abney_Park_Cemetery) have indeed been indexed, and you can view the database on the website of the [Abney Park Cemetery Indexing Project](http://freepages.rootsweb.com/%7Eabneypark/genealogy/abneyy.html), which is hosted on Rootsweb.

Note that the webpage hasn't been updated since April 2001, and the counter on the homepage appears to be broken.  Nevertheless, I was able to find my relatives who are buried there without difficulty.

Just click on the initial of the family name that you are interested in on the homepage, and go from there.  More information about searching can be found at the [Surname Search](http://freepages.rootsweb.com/%7Eabneypark/genealogy/abney-surn.html#top) link on the Project's homepage.

---

The [Basic Search](http://www.devsys.co.uk/ap/Basic_Search.asp) on the [Abney Park Cemetery Index 2005](http://www.devsys.co.uk/ap/Homepage.asp) also still works (again, I was able to locate my relatives who are buried there), and you can access more functions if you register.